# How to enter view-only mode when browsing Emacs source code from help?

Tags: elisp, hooks, advice, help-mode

When I browse Emacs help for functions via `C-h f`, I often want to peek into the Elisp/C implementation. I want to enter `view-mode` automatically when I access source code this way to avoid unnecessary modification. Is there a hook or function I can advise to accomplish this?

Comment: Here is what I use to prevent accidental modification of any of my files that open in `emacs-lisp-mode` and I just do `C-x C-q` if I want to edit the source code.  `(defun set-buffer-read-only () (setq buffer-read-only t)) (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'set-buffer-read-only)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (after a night of sleep):** This answer has a major flaw: it enables `view-mode` when navigating to *any* function, not just Emacs sources. This can be fixed, but you're better off using [the answer by **@phils**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3681/2355).

By doing `C-h f describe-function RET` and then reading the source code of `describe-function` I discovered that it creates a "button" of a special type for links to function definitions: `help-function-def`.

Running `zrgrep` with this string ("`help-function-def`") pointed me to `help-mode.el.gz`.

After all this digging around we can replace this button type with our own (note the comment in the code):

```
(define-button-type 'help-function-def
  :supertype 'help-xref
  'help-function (lambda (fun file)
               (require 'find-func)
               (when (eq file 'C-source)
                 (setq file
                       (help-C-file-name (indirect-function fun) 'fun)))
               ;; Don't use find-function-noselect because it follows
               ;; aliases (which fails for built-in functions).
               (let ((location
                      (find-function-search-for-symbol fun nil file)))
                 (pop-to-buffer (car location))
                 (if (cdr location)
                     (goto-char (cdr location))
                   (message "Unable to find location in file")))
                   (view-mode t)) ; <= new line: enable view-mode
  'help-echo (purecopy "mouse-2, RET: find function's definition"))
```

As far as I can tell there is no function to add advice to: Emacs uses a `lambda` here. On the other hand (as pointed out by **@rationalrevolt**) one can replace the `help-function` property of the `help-function-def` button type:

```
(require 'help-mode)
(let ((help-func (button-type-get 'help-function-def 'help-function)))
  (button-type-put 'help-function-def 'help-function
                   `(lambda (func file)
                      (funcall ,help-func func file) (view-mode t))))
```

Comment: I think I can try to use `button-type-get` and `button-type-put` to replace the lambda with my own that forwards to the existing lambda.

Comment: @rationalrevolt: Good idea! (Seems a bit fragile, but I suppose this is fragile too.)

Comment: @rationalrevolt: Please see the updated answer. (Can't have newlines in comments, it seems...)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying something similar but being a newbie to elisp I was bitten by the dynamic binding and couldn't get my closure to work :)

Answer (score 17):

You can use [directory-local variables](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables) to make Emacs' source files read-only by default. (See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Directory Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>).

Create a file called `.dir-locals.el` at the root of the directory tree you wish to protect, with the following contents:

```el
((nil . ((eval . (view-mode 1)))))
```

**Edit:** Michał Politowski points out in the comments that enabling `view-mode` in this way is problematic, because when you dismiss the buffer with <kbd>q</kbd> it also disables the mode, meaning that the next time you visit that buffer `view-mode` will not be enabled.

**Edit 2:** Constantine has provided a solution to that problem in the comments below:

```el
((nil . ((eval . (when buffer-file-name (view-mode-enter nil #'kill-buffer))))))
```

This usefully adds a test to ensure that the buffer is already visiting a file, but the key change is the use of `view-mode-enter` instead of `view-mode`, as the former takes an `EXIT-ACTION` argument which determines what to do when <kbd>q</kbd> is typed. In this case the exit action is to kill the buffer, ensuring that the next time the file is visited it will again end up in `view-mode`.

**Edit 3:** Following that path, we can also see that the specified `EXIT-ACTION` is ultimately passed to the `view-mode-exit` function, and its docstring gives us an alternative solution:

```
view-no-disable-on-exit is a variable defined in `view.el'.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
If non-nil, View mode "exit" commands don't actually disable View mode.
Instead, these commands just switch buffers or windows.
This is set in certain buffers by specialized features such as help commands
that use View mode automatically.
```

Hence we can use the following:

```el
((nil . ((eval . (when buffer-file-name
                   (setq-local view-no-disable-on-exit t)
                   (view-mode-enter))))))
```

---

I use the alternative approach which you can specify entirely in your init file (as opposed to creating a `.dir-locals.el` file), and I simply make the files read-only rather than using `view-mode`. My config looks like this:

```el
;; Emacs
(dir-locals-set-class-variables
 'emacs
 '((nil . ((buffer-read-only . t)
           (show-trailing-whitespace . nil)
           (tab-width . 8)
           (eval . (whitespace-mode -1))))))

(dir-locals-set-directory-class "/usr/local/src/emacs" 'emacs)
(dir-locals-set-directory-class "/usr/local/share/emacs" 'emacs)
(dir-locals-set-directory-class "/usr/share/emacs" 'emacs)
```

Obviously you can do the same thing for your elpa directory, and any other directory which contains third-party source code.

Comment: Great! This is clearly better than what I came up with. (What was I thinking of? I know about and use `.dir-locals.el` myself...)

Comment: I've been something along the same lines based on a `find-file-hook` and a `read-only-dirs` list, but I like this approach.

Comment: This looks like a very clean approach. I have one minor problem though. With `((nil . ((eval . (view-mode 1)))))` what is the simplest way to make `View-quit` kill the buffers accessed via help? Otherwise after exiting the source view by pressing `q`, the buffer stays behind and when later accessing sources from the same file from help again view-mode is not started.

Comment: Michał Politowski: Right you are. I've updated the answer to incorporate that fact, but I don't have a workaround. Constantine's (edited) answer may be the best solution for using `view-mode`.

Comment: Today I figured out that I need a workaround for the issue pointed out by @MichałPolitowski --- and I found one: use `((nil . ((eval . (when buffer-file-name (view-mode-enter nil #'kill-buffer))))))` (note `(view-mode-enter ...)` instead of `(view-mode 1)`). This way pressing `q` kills the buffer and `view-mode` *is* enabled the next time I visit the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to add a [hook](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFunc):

```
(add-hook 'find-function-after-hook 'view-mode)
```

Comment: This is better than my monstrosity, but still does not really match the question: it turns on `view-mode` when navigating to *any* function using `C-h f`, not just Emacs sources.

Comment: Experimentally, the help links don't actually run this hook. It looks like only the interactive `find-THING` commands utilise this hook, and the help buttons bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not address your specific case, but the more general case of switching to `view-mode` whenever you visit a source file from a help buffer. I'm offering it as an alternative  to @Constantine's answer, since it wasn't readable as a comment.

I looks like I originally got this from the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViewMode).

```
(defadvice find-function-search-for-symbol (after view-function-source last (symbol type library) activate)
  "When visiting function source via Help, switch to view-mode"
  (with-current-buffer (car ad-return-value)
    (view-mode 1)))

(defadvice find-variable-noselect (after view-var-source last (variable &optional file) activate)
  "When visiting variable source via Help, switch to view-mode"
  (with-current-buffer (car ad-return-value)
    (view-mode 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works for built-in documentation and an example showing how to extend it to ELPA. It works by matching the path to the current file against some regexes and applying `read-only-mode` if any of them match.

Note that the buffer is read-only-ified if you visit it through `dired` as well, not just through help.

I added a hook that runs after entering `emacs-lisp-mode` that checks if the path to the file matches `/\.el\.gz$/`, and applies read-only mode if it does.

```
(defun readonly-if-el-gz ()
  (cond
   ((string-match "\\.el\\.gz\\'" (or (buffer-file-name) ""))
    (read-only-mode +1))))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'readonly-if-el-gz)
```

Here's an example that checks ELPA too, using the heuristic that any path containing `.emacs.d/elpa` is actually ELPA code.

```
(defun readonly-if-internal ()
  (let
      ((name (or (buffer-file-name) "")))
    (cond
     ((string-match "\\.el\\.gz\\'" name) (read-only-mode +1))
     ((string-match "\\.emacs\\.d/elpa" name) (read-only-mode +1)))))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'readonly-if-internal)
```