# How can I avoid accidentally editing installed packages while still being able to install new packages?

Tags: init-file, package

I end up looking at source files of packages I have installed fairly often and want to avoid accidentally editing them while I am viewing them.  After looking at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3681/767, I put together this:

```
(dir-locals-set-class-variables
 'emacs
 '((nil . ((buffer-read-only . t)
           (show-trailing-whitespace . nil)
           (tab-width . 8)
           (eval . (whitespace-mode -1))))))
(dir-locals-set-directory-class (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa") 'emacs)
(dir-locals-set-directory-class
 (locate-dominating-file (locate-library "winner") "lisp") 'emacs)
```

This worked fine until I went to install a new package.  At that point, the machinery kicks in to create autoloads and then fails to write them because they are considered to be read-only.

I suspect I could do something with `defadvice` but maybe my whole approach needs to be rethought.  Has anyone else already solved this?

Comment: You can also use `C-x C-q` to change a buffer's read-only status. (And there's always undo ;-).)

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` about the failure to install packages with such a config.

Comment: The package [hardhat](https://github.com/rolandwalker/hardhat) can help here, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked around this before by making an exception for autoloads. From my config:

```
(define-derived-mode emacs-lisp-autoloads-mode emacs-lisp-mode "Autoloads"
  "Marker mode for package autoloads files.")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("autoloads\\.el\\'" . emacs-lisp-autoloads-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("loaddefs\\.el\\'" . emacs-lisp-autoloads-mode))

(dir-locals-set-class-variables
 'read-only
 '((nil . ((buffer-read-only . t)))
   ;; Keep autoloads writeable so we can update packages
   (emacs-lisp-autoloads-mode . ((buffer-read-only . nil)))))
```

This defines a mode for autoloads and associates it with the typical file names. Then the dir-locals class sets the buffer to read-only, except for buffers in emacs-lisp-autoloads-mode. You can associate this 'read-only class with your elpa directory as you were doing before.

Answer (score 4):

Adding following hack, which temporarily inhibits read-only-mode, is working for me:

```
(advice-add
 'package-install-from-archive
 :around (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
           (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
              (apply orig-fun args))))
```

The full relevant config looks like:

```
(dir-locals-set-directory-class (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa") 'emacs)
(dir-locals-set-directory-class
 (locate-dominating-file (locate-library "winner") "lisp") 'emacs)
(advice-add
 'package-install-from-archive
 :around (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
           (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
              (apply orig-fun args))))
```

Comment: What about just let-binding `inhibit-read-only` ?

Comment: Sounds even better than what I came up with.  I’ll give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: inhibit-read-only worked great, I have updated the the answer with that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your config is sound.  Too bad it trips up package.el.
While waiting for this to be fixed, you can try the following instead:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-find-file-tweaks)
(defun my-find-file-tweaks ()
  (when (and (file-in-directory-p buffer-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa")
             (not delay-mode-hooks))
    (read-only-mode 1)))
```

where the `(not delay-mode-hooks)` test is an ugly hack that tries to detect the case where package.el generates the autoloads.

Comment: I don't understand how this hack is intended to work, but I gave it a try and  I got the same failure (about trying to modify a read-only buffer).